# Differently able people and their "Vinyana"

Tags: theravada, mind

Say i am a Differently able person and i cant move my arms so how does my Vinyana work?

Is that part of my "Kaya Vinyana" (The vinyana that works with the body) deactivated or lost contact with the arms?

What is the connection between the Vinyana and a uncontrollable body part like arms or legs?

I am not reffering this question about Blind,Deaf or Mute people only about the people who are not able to use existing and functioning body parts

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, Vinyana is always present, but it is the function and sharpness of the faculty that distinguish the different experiences or what is felt through the faculty. In the context of mediation your faculties should be sharp for your the experience the reality as it is, so a person with diminished faculties generally will not be able to progress in Vipassana.

E.g. if your arm is lost then your limps then you have are not without or diminished Kaya Vinyanaya but due to the fact that a part of the faculty is missing there is not chance that to make contact of even if there is contact I does not register in the case of a blind person.

The ability to move is Power or Ability (Irdi) in which our body reacts to our intentions. The function of Vinyanaya is to register any contact which comes through the sense doors.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Suminda please continue explaining furthermore.Some examples might help us.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Vinyanaya that "takes care of body". Kaya Vinyanaya arises as soon as body contacts with something (*Kayan patichcha pottabbecha uppajjathi kayavinyanan* - Madupindika Sutta). So if one can feel the body, kaya vinyana arises. Irrespective of its mobility.

Comment: Thank you for the answer sajeewa please continue explaining furthermore.Some examples might help us.

Answer (score 1):

Vinaya is consciousness. If you keep Buddhist doctrine aside then it is simple to describe consciousness. Kaya Vinaya is a description of that part of consciousness which is in touch with body. Consciousness can be thought of very fine grained body which becomes grosser and takes shape of various subtle bodies some of which are described by terms as Pranic, Astral etc. Consciousness in its subtlest forms governs life and death. If you are alive then it means Vinaya is there. But if you do not have control over a limb it means Vinaya has lost touch due to malfunction of grosser bodies inside. Kaya Vinaya is that part of consciousness which is in direct contact with body. Since Buddha did not want people to experiment with grosser bodies he never spoke about them. I am sure anybody who meditates and adopts a right lifestyle will start witnessing subtle bodies inside.